# Como atualizar simplesadapter na tela principal em outra tela?

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho uma activity principal(`MenuBalcao.class`), e nela se encontra um listviewer que lista itens de pedido. Existe outra activity(`Selecao_Sabores_Produto_Balcao`)onde eu pesquiso os itens do pedido.

Porem quando eu tento mandar itens da tela de busca(Selecao_Sabores_Produto_Balcao.class) para a principal(MenuBalcao.class), os dados vão normal porem não consigo atualizar a listviewer dessa tela principal((MenuBalcao.class)) da minha tela secundaria.

Meu código da tela principal(MenuBalcao.class) para inserir dados(Selecao_Sabores_Produto_Balcao.class):

```
public  void  inserirListViewItensProduto(String pID, String pDescricao, String pUnidade,
                                             String pValor, String pQtde, String pObs, String pSabores) {


        mapPedido = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapPedido.put("id_produto", pID);
        mapPedido.put("tx_descricao", pDescricao);
        mapPedido.put("tx_unidade", pUnidade);
        mapPedido.put("qtde", pQtde);
        mapPedido.put("vl_preco", pValor);

        Float result = Float.parseFloat(pQtde) * Float.parseFloat(pValor);

        mapPedido.put("sub_total", String.valueOf(result));

        Log.i("CHEGOU AQUI: ",  " INSERIR ITENS " );

        dataPedido.add(mapPedido);

       // sAdapPedido.notifyDataSetChanged();

        sAdapPedido.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // getAtualizaPedido();


    }
```

meu codido que envia dados dos itens da minha tela segundaria

```
btnInserir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInserir);
        btnInserir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //inserindo dados na lista de MenuBalcao


                if (editQdte.getText().toString().length() > 0) {

                    TextViewID        = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCodProduto);
                    TextViewDescricao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDescricaoProduto);
                    TextViewUnd       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUnidadeProduto);
                    TextViewValor     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewValorProduto);

                    String pID        = TextViewID.getText().toString();
                    String pDescricao = TextViewDescricao.getText().toString();
                    String pUnidade   = TextViewUnd.getText().toString();
                    String pValor     = TextViewValor.getText().toString();
                    String pQtde      = editQdte.getText().toString();
                    String pObs       = editObs.getText().toString();
                    String pSabores   = editSabores.getText().toString();

                    MenuBalcao menuBalcao = new MenuBalcao();
                    menuBalcao.inserirListViewItensProduto(pID, pDescricao, pUnidade,
                            pValor, pQtde, pObs,pSabores);


                    Toast.makeText(Selecao_Sabores_Produto_Balcao.this, "Produto adcionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else
                    Toast.makeText(Selecao_Sabores_Produto_Balcao.this, "A Qtde estar Vazia", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

        });
```

So ressaltando: os dados vão certinho porem ele da um erro na linha de código
nesse ponto:

```
sAdapPedido.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Na minha tela principal.

Erro da minha tela de log

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o erro ? Coloque a descrição do erro na pergunta

Comment: segue o erro do tocat

Comment: Shutting down VM
10-14 02:13:30.827 5807-5807/com.svagp.post.postmobilesvagp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.svagp.post.postmobilesvagp, PID: 5807

Comment: O que é MenuBalcao?

Comment: vou colocar as 3 actvitiy para ficar melhor.. e melhor entendimento

Comment: Mais MenuBalcao é onde eu coloco o itens selecionado da activity Selecao_Sabores_Produto_Balcao.this